# How to escape ",< and all special characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

How to escape all special characters in javaScript.

We are using this, but it's not working:

```
<input type = "text" value="' }{ " : ? > < \ ] [ ' ; / . ,">
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript, this is HTML.

Comment: You need to escape it before it gets put into the html. Trying to fix it with javascript after won't work

Comment: `<` or `>` won't cause any problem inside of `value`, the problem is the `"` quote. 

Use a backslash before `"` and `'` otherwise the browser will think you are ending the area where you can put the value in. 

`value="\' }{ \" : ? > < \ ] [ \' ; / . ,"`

Comment: @DeepakKamat a backslash will not work. It's the HTML parser that's involved, not the JavaScript parser.

Comment: Oh. I should have tried myself before blatantly suggesting anything. Thanks for the point out, Pointy. Your name's on point. ;)

Answer (score 10):

You need just to exchange `"` with `&quot;`.

A good idea is to take some more HTML entities:

- `<` replace with `&lt;`
- `>` replace with `&gt;`

```html
<input type = "text" value="' }{ &quot; : ? &gt; &lt; \ ] [ ' ; / . ,">
```

Comment: Main reason I say that is that I'd do this with a single centralized HTML escape routine, and in the interest of avoiding dumb bugs I'd prefer to have just *one* of them that always escapes any character that might be "dangerous" in some situations. It doesn't hurt, after all.

Answer (score 3):

By using the browsers DOM you can let the browser do the work for you.

Make a HTML node, append a text node to it and put in the text node the html code you wish to escape.
Only for double quotes you might need to account by doing a replace on them to `&quot;` and single quotes to `&#39;`

```js
function htmlspecialchars(str) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var text = document.createTextNode(str);
  div.appendChild(text);
  return div.innerHTML.replace(/"/g,'&quot;').replace(/'/g,'&#39;');
}

console.log(htmlspecialchars("<html>"));
console.log(htmlspecialchars("<!DOCTYPE=\"RUBBISH\">"));
console.log(htmlspecialchars("' }{ \" : ? > < \\ ] [ ' ; / . ,"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are either trying to escape the following as an HTML attribute value or as a JavaScript string

```
' }{ " : ? > < \ ] [ ' ; / . ,
```

#### As an HTML attribute value, the following

```
<input type="text" value="' }{ " : ? > < \ ] [ ' ; / . ,">
```

could be fixed by escaping the double quote after `value=`

```
<input type="text" value="' }{ &quote; : ? > < \ ] [ ' ; / . ,">
```

`&quote;` will be rendered as the `"` character.

Ideally you should also escape all HTML reserved characters (> and < become respectively `&gt;` and `&lt;`)

```
<input type="text" value="' }{ &quote; : ? &gt; &lt; \ ] [ ' ; / . ,">
```

#### As a  JavaScript string

The string `' }{ " : ? > < \ ] [ ' ; / . ,` must be escaped differently whether you use single quote delimiters (') or double quote delimiters ("")

Single quotes

```
var str = '\' }{ " : ? > < \ ] [ \' ; / . ,';
```

Double quotes

```
var str2 = "' }{ \" : ? > < \ ] [ ' ; / . ,";
```